# VSCode python tasks

Tags: vscode, task

Trato de configurar una tarea que ejecute python con argumentos.

He conseguido ejecutar el fichero principal, pero el argumento no lo coge igual que si lo ejecutase desde consola.

Se trata de leer un archivo de configuración y pienso, que al no estar ejecutándolo al mismo nivel de carpeta sino uno superior, la ejecución me da errores.

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "execute odoo",
            "command": "${workspaceFolder}/odoo/odoo-bin",
            "args": [
                "--config=${workspaceFolder}/odoo/debian/odoo.conf"
            ],
            "type": "shell",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "new",
                "focus": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el apartado [`options` dentro del `task`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) para definir el directorio de ejecución del comando:

```
{
    "label": "execute odoo",
    "command": "${workspaceFolder}/odoo/odoo-bin",
    "args": [
        "--config=${workspaceFolder}/odoo/debian/odoo.conf"
    ],
    "type": "shell",
    "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/odoo"
    },
    "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
    },
    "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "new",
        "focus": true
    }
}
```

Comment: pruebo y te digo

Comment: a la primera! gracias!